# Jenkins test result parsing

Tags: xml, testing, jenkins, junit

I've got a Jenkins with a lot of jobs. These jobs do tests and produce test outputs in XML. Those XML test results look - pretty standard - like this:

```
<testsuites name="testsuitesname">
  <testsuite name="testsuitename">
    <testcase classname="classname" name="testcasename">
      blabla
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

When you use the *Post-build action* *Publish JUnit test result report* (found on the configuration page of a job) the structure of those published results of a build (in Jenkins) will be like this:

1. `<root>` (headline: package)
2. `<classname>` (headline: class)
3. `<testcasename>` (headline: test name)

There is no `<testsuitesname>` and no `<testsuitename>` in this hierarchy like it is in the XML files.

Is there any option to either:

1. add the `<testsuitesname>` and `<testsuitename>` to the hierarchy in the test result publishing hierarchy of a Jenkins build:

   1. (`<root>`)
   2. `<testsuitesname>`
   3. `<testsuitename>`
   4. `<classname>`
   5. `<testclassname>`

or

2. somehow add more hierarchy to the `<testcase>` tag?

Background: Because my test results are quite large (big amount) I want to add more hierarchy/structure to it and not just two levels (like it is now) to gain more overview over all of those results.

Can anybody help me or had a similar problem?

Best

Andy

Comment: Hi Gerold - this option is in every job you create or configure under post-build-actions.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately I found no easy answer to change the behaviour of Jenkins in structuring the teststructure different. However, I found an improvement in my case which I want to share.

The hierarchy of test results in Jenkins is the following:

1. Package
2. Class
3. Test name

Those can be defined within the `<testcase>`-tag as the following:

```
<testcase classname="packagename.classname" name="testname">
```

So within "name" you can define the last part of the hierarchy - the test name. Within "classname" you can define the first two parts of the hierarchy - the package and the class, seperated by a dot.

Keep in mind that there is only one dot allowed. It is not possible to create a deeper hierarchy by just adding more "seperated parts" in the classname tag only by adding more dots. If there are more dots than one, the last one counts.

So a "complete" example:

```
<testsuites name="testsuitesname">
  <testsuite name="testsuitename">
    <testcase classname="packagename.classname" name="testname">
      blabla
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```